# paging in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, paging

I have this code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Model_Core_BlogPost_GetLatestPaging] 
@PageSize INT,
@CurrentPage INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PageStart int, @PageEnd int
SET @PageStart = @CurrentPage * @PageSize
set @PageEnd = @PageStart + @PageSize

;with C as (

SELECT
e.blogpostid, 
e.PreviewText, 
e.Headline, 
e.URLHeadline, 
u.Blogname, 
u.imageurl AS ImageURL, 
e.CommentsCount, 
e.HitsCount, 
e.Created, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by e.created desc) as rownum

FROM BlogPosts e
INNER JOIN Users u ON e.BlogUserID = u.UserID
WHERE e.[Status] = 1 and e.Deleteddate is null
)

SELECT *
FROM C
WHERE rownum > @pagestart
AND rownum <= @pageend

END
```

I have issues when the @CurrentPage is a large number and I often get sql timeouts in my application.

Any ideas for a solution ?

Comment: Please post your execution plan

Comment: Can you provide the schema information for anything related to BlogPosts and Users? My guess is you can add an index to help out.

Comment: I have already added indexes to the things in the where clause. Is it better to develop another SP to run when the page is a high number ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as indexes are in place I would suggest splitting this query in 2 separate.

First run the ranking function and filter on blogposts, insert the result into a temporaray table and afterwards join the temporary table with users possibly by using an option loop join (the temp table will have very little rows comparing to users and loop join is perfect for this situation).

This way your join will have much less rows to parse. Also, are you sure the blogposts.created column has index? Row_number will perform ordering on this field.

Comment: I thought that temp tables were a bit slower... I have double checked that I have an index on the created column.

Comment: It depends.... In this specific case it should be much faster, especially if you manage to add indexes into it. It will have only the rows for the current page and I think you will gain significant performance if you join only those few rows. You could use a cte for this but I don't trust them and in this specific situation you won't gain something.